# PBR transparent fence texture node set-up not working

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, pbr

Thanks in advance for your help!

I'm working with a transparent wire fence PBR texture, and I cannot get the space between the wires to be transparent. (I've also tried on a simple plane mesh - same results)

I've tried with two different materials:

Picture 1: https://www.texturecan.com/details/134/

Picture 2: https://cc0textures.com/view.php?tex=Fence06

What am I missing here?

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: Have you tried individually selecting the "in-between" wire faces in edit mode and applying a transparent modifier to them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on your "right panel" (just under the option "backface culling"), on "blend mode", it is set to "opaque". As you are using Eevee, click there and just choose another blend mode, like "alpha clip" or "alpha blend".

[image]

Comment: other settings that you may need to pay attention when using PBR under Eevee are:
Render → Screen Space Reflections ON;
Render → Screen Space Reflections → Refraction ON;
Material → Principled BSDF and Transparent BSDF into Mix shader;
Material → Principled BSDF → Transmission 1.000;
Material → Mix shader Fac mostly all the way to Transparent;
Material → Settings → Blend Mode Alpha Blend;
Material → Settings → Screen Space Refraction ON;

Comment: That worked! thank you MCunha!